# Можно ли так формулировать?

Tags: грамотная-речь

В диалоге после примеров и доводов выдвигается мнение в таком предложении:
**Считаю изменение работы до одного часа обусловленным.**
Грамотно ли так писать?

Answer (score 1):

Причастие "обусловленный" само по себе неинформативно и требует дополнений, указывающих, *чем именно обусловлено* то, о чём говорится, или уточнений, *в каком отношении* это *обусловлено*. В вашем предложении **нет** таких пояснительных слов. Однако в редких случаях **можно** построить предложение с "обусловленным" в конце.

> Критиками столь необычный литературный приём был признан *контекстно
>   обусловленным.*
>
> Такое развитие событий для специалистов выглядело *исторически
>   обусловленным.*

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего, кто-то хотел сказать: *считаю обоснованным*.

Впрочем, если были оговорены **условия**, без выполнения которых некоторое изменение не может быть введено, то такое изменение можно считать **обусловленным**.

*Изменение работы до одного часа* — непонятно что. Скорее всего, имелось в виду
*удлинение (сокращение) рабочего дня не более чем на один час.*

Comment: Если это перечесление доводов и примеров к ним, которые между собой взаимосвязанны и по отдельности не могут действовать?
После чего следуют предложения такого типа как "итог" к примеру:
Считаю изменение работы "прииера 1" до одного часа обусловленным.
Считаю изменение работы "примера 2"до одного часа обусловленным.

Comment: Доводы и примеры не есть условия введения каких-либо изменений. Пример условий: чрезвычайная ситуация, финансовый кризис, невыполнение квартального плана. Если договорились, что при этих  условиях рабочий день может быть удлинён, то можно считать удлинение рабочего для обусловленным   (этими условиями)

Comment: Иными словами, администрация сможет в будущем удлинить рабочий день, только если произойдет что-то из перечисленного.

Comment: Лучше будет, если Вы приведете более широкий контекст.